# Oracle - check if queue table exists before flushing it

Tags: oracle11g

How do you check if the queue table exist before flushing it.

I have used the below syntax to create queue table

```
CREATE type Message_typ as object (
subject     VARCHAR2(30),
text        VARCHAR2(80)); 
BEGIN
   dbms_aqadm.CREATE_QUEUE_TABLE (
      queue_table          => 'XX'
     ,queue_payload_type   => 'Message_typ'
   );
END;
```

And the below code to purge the flush table:

```
declare
  l_type                      dbms_aqadm.aq$_purge_options_t;
begin
  l_type.block := true;
  l_type.delivery_mode := dbms_aq.buffered;
  dbms_aqadm.purge_queue_table(queue_table       => 'XX',
                               purge_condition   => '',
                               purge_options     => l_type);
  l_type.block := true;
  l_type.delivery_mode := dbms_aq.persistent;
  dbms_aqadm.purge_queue_table(queue_table       => 'XX',
                               purge_condition   => '',
                               purge_options     => l_type);
end;
```

Please guide how to check if the queue table exists and if exists do a purge.

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't bother checking if the queue table exists first; presumably you're expecting it to be there most of the time? Instead, I would handle the exception that is returned if the queue table doesn't exist, and then create the queue table (or whatever action you want to take place at this point).

Comment: Hi Bony, I wanted to check if queue table exist and then purge the data. As I calling this query from Talend I wanted to handle the table check at Oracle end. Do you know how to check if queue table exists?

Comment: Again, I say, don't check first, do the purge and then catch (and handle) the exception that occurs if the queue doesn't exist. I assume that the queue is likely to be there most of the time, meaning you only have to handle the case where it's missing very occasionally.

Comment: Thanks. ORA-24002: QUEUE_TABLE name does not exist. declared table_does_not_exist exception;  WHEN table_does_not_exist then          dbms_output.put_line('table dose not exists'); does not handle the exception. I have to specify as others.

Comment: Is there any specific exception name I could use. Alternatively the help ask me to query USER_QUEUE_TABLES table which I do not want to go for it as you say

Comment: looks like you're missing the pragma exception_init to tie your exception to the ORA-24002 error number

Comment: Thank you. This has fixed my issue. I am not Oracle developer.